# UK Provisional Driver's License on EEA FP Entry Clearance Visa

Tags: united-kingdom, driving-license

The requirements for UK Provisional Driver's License says:

> **Residency**
> You can only get a GB licence if you are normally and lawfully resident in Great Britain. To be normally resident you must usually live in Great Britain for 185 days in each calendar year.
>
> Applicants who are not UK citizens or nationals of an EU or EEA country will not be considered normally resident if they:
>
> - do not have leave to remain in the UK, or
> - are in the country on a temporary basis without leave to remain either while awaiting a decision to stay in the UK or following a decision refusing such an application.

Where does someone on a EEA FP Entry Clearance Visa sit on this? I'm not sure if the "temporary basis without leave to remain either while awaiting a decision to stay in the UK" applies or not?

Comment: Is the person a "family member" or an "extended family member"?  Had the person applied for a residence card or, more likely at this point, for the EU settlement scheme?

Comment: @phoog Spouse. Surinder Singh application submitted.